# неправильная отрисовка окна

Tags: java, graphics, jframe

```
package dino;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Dino extends JFrame implements KeyListener  {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        Dino frame = new Dino();
        frame.setSize(1200,1000);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setContentPane(panel);
        panel.setBackground(Color.white);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        Font font;
        font = new Font("Calibri",Font.BOLD,25);
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.setFont(font);
        g.drawString("Нажмите пробел чтобы играть", 300, 475);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke) {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent ke) {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke) {

    }
}
```

при выполнении копирует в окно место где окно находилось во время старта программы

Answer (score 0):

Переопределив метод `paint` вы лишили систему возможности нарисовать что-либо. Вам надо сделать вызов метода предка. Вот так

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g){
    super.paint(g); // вызов метода предка
    Font font;
    font = new Font("Calibri",Font.BOLD,25);
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.setFont(font);
    g.drawString("Нажмите пробел чтобы играть", 300, 475);
}
```

А в целом не стоит переопределять что-то в объекте класса **JFrame**. Рисовать лучше в в объекте **JPanel**.